# Add a "new line" in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to create a table with images in first cell and information about the pic in second cell.

I need to add different information in one cell, like that:

```
cellTwo.innerHTML = arr_title[element] + arr_tags[element];
```

Is it possible to add a "new line" there?
I mean like that:

```
cellTwo.innerHTML = arr_title[element] + "/n" + arr_tags[element];
```

Comment: yes, it is does not work

Comment: HTML newlines are ignored by default. Use <br> tag

Comment: If it helps, innerHTML will store newlines accurately in the DOM. They are only combined with any other whitespace and treated as a single space during rendering.

Answer (score 50):

The simplest way is by adding a line break as html

```
cellTwo.innerHTML = arr_title[element] + "<br />" + arr_tags[element];
```

If you want your newlines to be treated literally, you could use the `<pre>` tag

```
cellTwo.innerHTML = 
    "<pre>" + arr_title[element] + "\n" + arr_tags[element] + "</pre>";
```

Comment: By using <pre> tag, the font size would become very small.

Comment: @zhang I'm not sure what you mean, to you can control the font size with CSS

Answer (score 16):

To round out your understanding:

Since it is html *(`innerHTML`)* it renders html and you can use any html you wish, so in this case simply add an good old fashioned `<br>`:

```
var test = document.getElementById('someElementId');
test.innerHTML = "The answer <br>to life, the universe, and everything...<br> is 42.";
```

If it were a string, such as in an alert box or text box etc. then /n would be correct:

```
alert('Never /n Forget your towel.');
```

Happy Coding!
        - $cr1ptN!nj@

Answer (score -2):

No, `<br />` does not work in asp .net but you can instead  write it like so

```
cellTwo.innerHTML = arr_title[element] + arr_tags[element]; arr_title[element] + "/n" + arr_tags[element];
```

Edit - alternative wrapped in code tags

```
cellTwo.innerHTML = arr_title[element] + arr_tags[element];
cellTwo.innerHTML += arr_title[element] + "/n" + arr_tags[element];
```

Semicolon ";" seems to act as line breaks
Remember the "+=" to assign multiple values to the string

Comment: `<br />` works perfectly fine in HTML generated from ASP.NET. `"/n"` doesn't mean a new line anywhere as far as I know. `\n` means a new line in a JavaScript string literal, but is treated like any other whitespace when converted to HTML. A semicolon does not act like a line break in JavaScript, a semicolon ends a statement. Sometimes a line break with cause a semicolon to be inserted automatically in JS. In short, absolutely everything about this answer is wrong (and mostly the exact opposite of correct)